# Python: The code disobeys the conditional depending on the input

Tags: python-2.7, class, while-loop, iteration

I'm making a hang man game. When I made the code with out a conditional and classes, it worked fine. Basically my issues with the code below are:

1. Only the letter "t" will match. I can't get any other letter to match.
2. If I enter "t" on the first try, then purposely get the next 4 letters wrong, it won't end until after 7 turns. Yet if I enter any other letter first, it will end after 4 wrong turns, like it should.

My questions....

1. How can I get it to match with the other letters that are in the `self.word` index?
2. Why is it not obeying the condition I set with the while loop in the main method if I enter "t" on my first try and get every other letter wrong thereafter?

   ```
   class Hang():

       def __init__(self):
           self.turns = 0
           self.word = ['t', 'h', 'i', 's']
           self.empty = ["__", "__", "__", "__"]
           self.wrong = []

       def main(self):
           while self.turns < 4:
               for i in self.word:
                   choice = raw_input("Enter a letter a-z: ")
                   if choice == i:
                       index = self.word.index(i)
                       self.empty.pop(index)
                       self.empty.insert(index, i)
                       print self.empty
                   else:
                       print "Wrong"
                       self.wrong.append(choice)
                       print self.wrong
                       print self.empty
                       self.turns += 1

   char1 = Hang()
   char1.main()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In the game of hangman you can guess any character in the phrase in any order. But you're using a for loop to go through each character in order and it is only correct if the player correctly guesses the characters in order

Try this instead

```
while self.turns < 4:

    choice = raw_input("Enter a letter a-z: ")

    # optional, if user enters more than a single letter
    if len(choice) > 1:
        print "invalid choice"
        continue                   # loop again from start

    index = self.word.index(choice)

    if index != -1:    
        # -1 indicates character in not int the string
        # so this block is only executed if character is
        # in the string

        self.empty[index] = choice     # no need to pop, you can simply change the value of the list at a given index

    else:
        print "wrong"
        self.turns += 1

    print self.empty
```

Comment: `index = self.word.index(i)` Where is the i in the index() method coming from?

Comment: @staredecisis sorry about that, should be index(choice)